# UICollectionView.scrollToItem(at:at:animated:) scroll the section out of view on IOS 17

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, ios17

I found that sometimes call `UICollectionView.scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` would scroll to a weird place on IOS 17 device and Mac OS 14 with Xcode 15, It's ok on below IOS 17 device (IOS 16...).

Here is a case:
[app view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7fJG.jpg)

Here is my set up :

```swift
private let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

view.addSubview(collectionView)
collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
   make.left.right.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
}

let collectionLayoutConfig = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
collectionLayoutConfig.scrollDirection = .horizontal
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: { section, _ in
    func getSection(cellCount: Int, extraInterGroupSpacing: Bool = false) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let cellSpacing = 10
        let cellInset = 24
        let cellLength = UICollectionView.cellLength(cellCount: cellCount, colViewLength: TT.screenWidth,
                                                     cellSpacing: cellSpacing, inset: cellInset)

        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(cellLength), heightDimension: .absolute(cellLength))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(cellLength))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        group.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
        group.interItemSpacing = NSCollectionLayoutSpacing.fixed(10)

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 24,
                                                        bottom: extraInterGroupSpacing ? 30 : 24,
                                                        trailing: 24)
        section.interGroupSpacing = extraInterGroupSpacing ? 20 : 10
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous

        return section
    }

    switch section {
    case 0:
        return getSection(cellCount: 7)
    case 1:
        return getSection(cellCount: 4, extraInterGroupSpacing: true)
    default:
        return getSection(cellCount: 4)
    }
}, configuration: collectionLayoutConfig)

collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
collectionView.register(cellType: CutoutCell.self)
collectionView.register(cellType: CutoutCellAnimated.self)
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

I call `scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)` to scroll content to center, and it excessive upward scrolling.

Has anyone encountered similar problems?

It should not excessive scrolling.

Update :
I found that set `collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false` would solve this issue.

Comment: Quick testing - cannot reproduce what you're seeing. We need more detail... what is the frame of your collection view? Do you have any other code involved, such a setting insets? With your current code, can you drag up to scroll the cells out-of-view, or is this only happening when you call `scrollToItem`?

Comment: Thanks for respone, I have updated another detail. I can drag up to scroll the cells out-of-view but it would scroll back when I release finger.